# Rails app vs video player

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html5-video

not so long ago began using reils and i have one question arose with the loading and processing of video ...
is there something like carrierwave for video ?

user upload video to the file public/video 
and in the DB created file with uploaded file name
and after that in a view ve create a video tag

there is something like this?

Comment: carrierwave is for uploading files, it can be used for videos too. It is not just for images but you will need to use a 3rd party video encoding service

Answer (score 0):

You might benefit from Nick DeSteffen's blog post on [Uploadify + CarrierWave + Zencoder + Video.js](http://www.nickdesteffen.com/blog/video-encoding-with-uploadify-carrierwave-and-zencoder)